# IE9 won't work in Angular2

Tags: internet-explorer, angular

I have just added the routing system to my very first angular2 app :

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Homepage",
    component: HomepageComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: "/clients/details/:id",
    name: "ClientsDetails",
    component: ClientsDetailsComponent
  }
])
```

While, it is working on most browser, it doesn't seem to work on IE9.
I am having the following error when I land on the first page (/home) :

```
"EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'pushState'
```

In my index.html I have :

```
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

Any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: ie9 don't have html5 history api.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to have this working on IE9 ?

Comment: no idea, it was green with IE9 before, now it is red - https://saucelabs.com/u/angular2-ci

Comment: may be latest version has a fix, - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6506

Comment: Not yet deployed apparently

Comment: Hi @Scipion, did you manage to get past this error? I am facing the same issue in RC1. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I did not mate :(